# Sublime Text 2 doesn't stay pinned to the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, sublime-text

I use Sublime Text 2 in Ubuntu.  The program downloads and runs on it's own without an installer (sort of like a portable app, I guess).  When I pin it to the launcher, it only stays until I restart the computer.  Then I have to dig it up again and repin it.  This wasn't an issue in 11.04.

Answer (score 4):

It won't stay in the launcher because it doesn't have a `*.desktop` file.  You can create a `*.desktop` file [by hand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) (surprisingly complicated!) or you can simply use [some guy's PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/sublime-text-2-ubuntu-ppa.html) to install Sublime Text 2.  (The package includes the requisite `*.desktop` file.)

Comment: I use AWN (a dock using pretty much the same technology with .desktop files) and can't pin Sublime Text 2 whatever I do... :-( I've installed Sublime Text 2 from the PPA and tried editing the ".desktop" file but nothing helps. Curiously, despite I've changed the icon in the .desktop file (and it has got changed in the system menu), AWN still uses the default Sublime icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Sublime Text 2 using the PPA,

Open the AWN settings

Go to the "Task Manager" and drag&drop Sublime Text from your menu to the list.