# Sublime text 2 can't be added to the launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, sublime-text

i'm running sublime text 2 on 12.04 and the issue that I'm facing is that it can't be added to the Unity launcher.

I run ST2 from the executable file that's there in it's folder and as with other apps i right-click the icon and select the `add to launcher` option. It adds it for then (although ST2 can't be launched from the icon on the launcher, strange) and when i reboot my machine, it's gone.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/70012/sublime-text-2-doesnt-stay-pinned-to-the-launcher